When switching between different applications, the scroll position of the mouse wheel is synchronized
The current system version I'm using is Ubuntu 24.04, and the window manager is X11. Let's say when I scroll to a certain lower position on the page in the browser, and then switch the window to Typora via Alt + Tab, at this time, if I scroll downwards, it will immediately jump to the scroll position in the browser. Moreover, this issue is not limited to these two software. VS Code also behaves like this. This is so uncomfortable. Has any friend encountered such a problem?

Maybe your graphics card is the culprit. If your computer has discrete graphics, it may be a hardware issue.

I just tried it. Unfortunately, when I switched to the Intel integrated graphics card, the same problem occurred. Also, I found that this might be a problem with the window manager. When I switched to Ubuntu on Wayland, this problem didn't occur. But unfortunately, Sogou Input Method doesn't work properly on the Wayland desktop. Besides, when the display is scaled to 125%, text editors like Typora and VS Code will be very blurry.

@kristen did you find any more info related to this? I'm experiencing the same problem since upgrading to 24.04

I found a solution to this problem here: https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/2331#issuecomment-1229371645
Installing the Alt+Tab Scroll Workaround gnome extension fixed the issue for me on Ubuntu 24.04.
Another possible workaround mentioned in that github thread is installing imwheel, though I personally haven't tried it.
